# PHP variable as Javascript popup not working

Tags: php, javascript, session, popup

I am using a PHP variable called LeagueLink.  When the user is not logged in I want the variable to read the text (Already have a league...) followed by a link to a popup window.  So far it is displaying correctly except when I click on the link nothing happens.  I think I just have a syntax error from mixing so much PHP and JS, but I can't figure out where.  Please help make the popup window link work if you can...

```
<?php 
 // this starts the session 
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['userid'];
 $message = "";
 if ($_SESSION['userid'] == "") {
    $message = "You must create an account or sign in to play!";
    $LeagueLink = "Already have a league...<a href='JavaScript:newPopup(\"http://www.yourfantasyfootballreality.com/signin.php\");' class='two'>Sign In</a>";
 } else {
    $message = "Hello, " .$_SESSION['userid'] . " make your picks!";
 }

 ?> 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-easing-compatibility.1.2.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/coda-slider.1.1.1.pack.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="http://www.indiana.edu/favicon.ico" />
        <title>YourFantasyFootballReality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />

    </head>
        <body>
            <?=$message?>
            <?=$LeagueLink?>
            <?=$ActionLink?>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The year is 2012. Please abandon popups now.

Comment: Because I'd like for your work to be as good as it can be! :) As a side note, what's the thinking behind the lines between the `body` tags? That doesn't look like valid PHP to me.

Comment: what lines between the body tags??

Comment: `<?=$message?>
            <?=$LeagueLink?>
            <?=$ActionLink?>`

Comment: how is this not valid php code??

Comment: You should not use the shorthand PHP `<? ?>`. This isn't always supported. Also, what do the assignment operators do before each of the variable declarations? You're assigning the value of each variable to what exactly?

Comment: Yes, I do know what I am talking about. Your PHP doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JavaScript:newPopup` is a function that needs to be defined.

I think what you are looking for is the following: You don't need javascript to open the page in a new window. Just set the `target` property of the link to `_blank`.

```
$LeagueLink = "Already have a league...<a href='http://www.yourfantasyfootballreality.com/signin.php' target='_blank' class='two'>Sign In</a>";
```

**EDIT**: If you want it popping up, rather than opening in a new tab, you can resize it immediately after it is spawned. Add the following to your javascript.

```
function newPopup()
{
var url='http://www.yourfantasyfootballreality.com/signin.php';
windowProperties = "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,statusbar=no,height=500px,width=500px,left=50%,top=50%";
popWin = window.open(url,'newWin',windowProperties);
}
```

and keep your PHP the same as before.

Comment: This is a popup. Do you want it to be smaller in size?

Comment: You can use jQuery UI to create pop-ups.